# output title as class in wordpress PHP

Tags: wordpress, class, filter, title, sanitize

I have add an easy  function filter in wordpress to add a class to a widget title by using the widget title as class and it works, but the title itself is not visible anymore afterwards.

What to add to this filter to show the title itself too, besides to the class outputting it does now?

```
function widget_title_as_class($title) { 
return '<div class="BlockHeader-text ' . sanitize_title($title) . '"></div>';
}
add_filter('widget_title', 'widget_title_as_class')
```

For instance:
without filter firebug says this:

```
<div class="header-tag-icon">
<div class="BlockHeader-text"> Search </div>
</div>
```

With filter the output html says this:

```
<div class="header-tag-icon">
<div class="BlockHeader-text">
<div class="header-tag-icon Search"></div>
</div></div>
```

See the title is now a class but the title itself is gone? Must be easy to fix?
Help me out PHP guys! Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function widget_title_as_class($title) { 
return '<div class="BlockHeader-text ' . sanitize_title($title) . '">'.sanitize_title($title).'</div>';
}
add_filter('widget_title', 'widget_title_as_class');
```

Because you are not passing value to the div

Comment: yes! thank you wordpresser, that does it, I see what you mean.  Thank you very much!